# launchd plist launching at startup but not supposed to

Tags: plist, launchd

Like it says on the tin, I've a launch script that is supposed to fire at 1.20 AM but seems to be firing shortly after the user logs in instead. Can anyone see what I've done wrong?

Is is the way I've written the ProgramArguments, reaching within the app's container to launch it? I've not had success launching the (applescript) app any other way i.e. `open ~/Library/CDesResources/Shutdown.app` didn't seem to work.

The plist is saved in `~/Library/LaunchAgents/shutdownAgent.plist` so it should only fire when that user is logged in correct?

Many thanks for your fresh eyes and expertise.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
    <plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>shutdownAget</string>
        <key>Nice</key>
        <integer>-20</integer>
        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
            <string>/Library/CDesResources/Shutdown.app/Contents/MacOS/applet</string>
        </array>
        <key>RunAtLoad</key>
        <false/>
        <key>ServiceDescription</key>
        <string>launch the shutdown script</string>
        <key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
        <dict>
            <key>Hour</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
            <key>Minute</key>
            <integer>20</integer>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    </plist>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the man page for `launchd.plist(5)`:

> Unlike cron which skips job invocations when the computer is asleep, launchd will start the job the next time the computer wakes up.  If multiple
>        intervals transpire before the computer is woken, those events will be coalesced into one event upon wake from sleep.

So `launchd` is correctly noticing at launch that the job didn't run at 01:20 and scheduling it for you.

Comment: Thank you Gram - What Im seeing seems to be a recursive loop however. So in my case I have a shutdown script, which is firing the first time the mac starts (on a newly imaged mac) and even after it has shut down and restarted, launchd continues to fires the script. Is it possible that my shutdown scrip is firing before launchd registers the fact it actually ran? I'd say my shutdownscript takes as long as 30second before firing `shudown -h now`. What is the best way to prevent this behaviour? Is launchd the best tool to be using for this job?